# Setting multiple jPanels to invisible at the same time

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm trying to set about 144 jPanels all setVisible(false) and I'd like to do it all at once rather than jPanel1.setVisible(false); 144 times. Is there an easier way to do this?
I've tried to put the panels in an array but I'm using GUI swing on netbeans and the jPanels are already declared when I put them into the jFrame and when I try putting them in an array and using a for loop I get a null pointer error.

It's probably easy but I've looked all over the web and can't even find a topic on it.

Once again trying to set multiple (144 to be exact) jPanels in a jFrame to visible false at one time.

Comment: "about 144 jPanels"  Not relevant to your question, but what GUI requires a gross of `JPanel` objects?!?

Comment: I have some doubts about performance in this situation (but that also depends a lot on what each JPanel contains). It might be useful to consider using the same "trick" as Swing uses for JList, JTable and JTree: CellRenderers that are single components used as "rubber stamps".

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you set a JPanel parent for those JPanels and hide it?

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the root pane or common parent and walk down the hierarchy looking for panels with a common property value. Almost every swing app I work on ends up with a find(Container, Predicate) helper function somewhere.